# Animated.css not working properly in materialized css

Tags: html, css, animation

animated.css not working properly in materialized css. I have follow all the steps in mentioned in github (i.e) added animated.css file in header and also jquery library.

But The all animate.css effects are loaded in first time. I can't show the animation when the window reached the scroll.

Here is my output: http://54.164.65.208/sequoia/

Comment: *«when the window reached the scroll»* is unclear.

Comment: Sorry for inconvenient @LouysPatriceBessette, When the element reached the window

Comment: add some scrollspy which adds a class to the element on screen